# jQuery Get div from another page

Tags: jquery

I want to get my product price in my website from the product page to the product short description in home page, i use this code to get it, but when i apply it; it repeated, this mean all product have the same price.

```
(function($) {
    var price = $('.post-home .post-title a');
    $.get(price.attr('href'), function(data) {
        $('.price-con').html('<span class="price">' + $(data).find('.in-price').text() + '</span>');
    }, "html");
})(jQuery);
```

So how to do this for each post without repeat.

Answer (score 0):

This is cause you are using "class" selector `$(".price-con")`

try this in your console:

`$('.price-con').lenght`  and throws you the count of DOM existing in the document.

**to Fix:**

Try to get unique ID like `$("#id_price_1")`, other unique data will work like:

```
data-value=""
data-product=""
```